# Autocompletion for Kotlin does not show any parent methods

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, autocomplete

When I create a new project in AndroidStudio 3.5 I don't get any methods of parent class in autocompletion. How can I show them there?

[image: autocompletion screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that any-other process running background in android studio.

if yes means wait until that process to complete and also try

```
file-->invalidate caches and restart
```

Comment: I don't know why this helped. I have tried deleting all `~/.android*`, `~/.Android*` directories, reinstalling Android Studio, even *invalidating the caches and restarting* but it didn't worked. I tried invalidating caches again and now it works like a charm. It's weird.